# Custom title bar is truncated by other layout

Tags: android, custom-titlebar, truncated

I defined a custom title bar using the following 3 lines:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(view);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

as explained in many posts, however the title bar is truncated by the content view I set, and I see only a part of it.
I tried to add margin top to the layout I set but it didn't help.

main layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_gravity="right 
android:background="@color/bgColor" 
android:gravity="right" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="277dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right" >

...
```

title bar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:background="#323331"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.95"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/logo1" />
```

Comment: Can you show screenshot ?

Comment: you can see it here: http://imgur.com/AsIjP4t the black title bar is about half the size (in height) of its real size

Comment: Can you show your layout file code of your custom layout?

Comment: Can you show us the **complete layouts**, please? It's hard to understand how do you connect the parts together.

Comment: the main layout I posted above simply has some more nested layout, EditText, TextView, etc. nothing special... I set the title & appropriate layout (I have multiple and I switch between them) using the code I wrote above, however I use LayoutInflater in order to find the layout I want to show, so the code is a bit more complex than the 3 lines I posted, but basically I just use setContentView, I guess this is the relevant code